# I have a code that removes actions for specific users on certain pages depending on page metavalue... but it only makes an array of 5?

Tags: php, wordpress

Update! Read to the bottom for solve!

```
 /*remove Edit Trash, and quickedit of pages with specific metavalues for certain roles
    */
    add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'remove_page_row_actions', 10, 2 ); // 2, not 1
    // pass $post object as second argument.
    function remove_page_row_actions( $actions, $post ) {
        global $current_user; 
        get_currentuserinfo(); 
        //specify roles except administrator (but you need to add child roles based off administrator ex. adminsub)
        if( 
            ( (!current_user_can('administrator') || current_user_can('adminsub') )
            ||
              // specify a list of role(s)
              ( current_user_can('adminsub') || current_user_can('author') )
            ) )
        { 
            //search which type of $post
            $post_types_affected = array('page');
            //Dynamically get 1 post ID's in an array for a post that matches multiple values (im repeating 1 pointlessly)
            //$array_of_values_to_match = array( '1', '1', '1' );
            $array_of_values_to_match = array( 1 );
            $metakey_to_match = 'checkboxmeta1';
            // set some initial args
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'meta_query' => array(),
                );
            // if there's more than 1 value, add the relation arg
            if( 1 < count( $array_of_values_to_match ) ){
                $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'AND';
            }
            // for each of the array values, add a meta query for that value
            foreach( $array_of_values_to_match as $val ){
                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'key' => $metakey_to_match,
                    'value' => $val,
                    'compare' => '='
                );
            }
            $postlistarray = get_posts( $args );
            //end of function which an array or post arrays which each contain a post ID and a metakey of 1
    
            //must create an array column, becuase that is what $x = array(111,212) does
            $post_ids_affected = array_column($postlistarray, 'ID');
    
            //check array_column for post IDs, and remove functionality below
            if ( in_array( $post->post_type, $post_types_affected )
                && in_array( $post->ID, $post_ids_affected ) ) 
            {
                unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
                unset( $actions['edit'] );
                unset( $actions['trash'] );
                unset( $actions['pa_duplicator'] );
            }
        }
        return $actions;
    }
```

`$post_ids_affected` ends up being something like

```
array(0=>1000 , 1=> 1023, ... 4 => 524)
```

but it only goes up to 4, when there are like 10 pages atleast that have metabox value of 1. and the post ID list is from most recently created to oldest... but 0 to 4 is only 5 pages...not sure why I cant pull more into my array?

---

chris Haas was able to see the issue so I changed

```
//set some initial args
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'meta_query' => array(),
    );
```

to this instead

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => get_post_types(),
  'meta_query' => array(),
  'numberposts' => -1,
   );
```

and it works! My next concern however is trying to get this to apply also to posts and to custom posts types.. since it only affects pages right now?

SOLVED:

I just made the above adjustment
and the 2 following

changed

```
//search which type of $post
    $post_types_affected = array('page');
```

to

```
//search which type of $post
    $post_types_affected = array('page' , 'post');
```

and the duplicated the filter for posts!

```
/*remove Edit Trash, and quickedit of pages with specific metavalues for certain roles
*/
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'remove_page_row_actions', 10, 2 ); // 2, not 1 
// pass $post object as second argument. 
function remove_page_row_actions( $actions, $post ) {
```

to this

```
/*remove Edit Trash, and quickedit of pages with specific metavalues for certain roles
*/
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'remove_page_row_actions', 10, 2 ); // 2, not 1 
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_page_row_actions', 10, 2 ); // 2, not 1 
// pass $post object as second argument. 
function remove_page_row_actions( $actions, $post ) {
```

Comment: could you make that IF a little more unreadable and uninteligable please

Comment: [`get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) defaults to 5. You need to set `numberposts` in args.

Comment: yes Chris! that was it! thanks for helping me out with my spaghetti code... I changed // set some initial args
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'meta_query' => array(),
 ); to this instead    $args = array(
  'post_type' => get_post_types(),
  'meta_query' => array(),
  'numberposts' => -1,
   ); .... any but it only filters "pages" still.. any idea how to also have this apply to posts and other custom post types?